# Plot from Cartesian to polar

Tags: c++, polar-coordinates

I'm using the Left and Right audio channels to create a Lissajous Vectorscope.  Left is x and Right is y, both which never goes beyond 1 and -1 values. These coordinates are also shifted at a 45 degree angle to give me the following view.

[image]

So I'm doing a very simple

```
// converting x and y value from (-1 - 1) to (0 - 1)
float x = LeftChannelValue/2 + 0.5
float y = RightChannelValue/2 + 0.5

// multiplying the width and height with X and Y to get a proper square
// width and height have to be the same value 
float new_X = x*(width*0.5)
float new_Y = y*(height*0.5)

// doing two dimensional rotating to 45 degrees so it's easier to read
float cosVal = cos(0.25*pi)
float sinVal = sin(0.25*pi)

float finalX = (((new_X*cosVal)-(new_Y *sinVal))) + (width*0.5) //adding to translate back to origin 
float finalY = ((new_X*sinVal) + (new_Y *cosVal))
```

This gives me the results on that picture.

How would I graph the polar coordinates so that it doesn't look like a square, it looks like a circle?
[image]
I'm trying to get this view but am absolutely confused about how that would correlate with the left and right. I'm using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system as a reference.

Comment: A Lissajous diagram doesn't involve a cartesian/polar transform - what are you aiming for here?

Comment: I already have a Lissajous diagram which is cartesian. I want to transform it into a polar graph that goes from 0 to 360 degrees. That's what I'm going for. I want to to look like this

http://help.izotope.com/docs/ozone/pages/images/5_stereoimage_vector.png

but 360 degrees instead of 180

Comment: Figured out what was wrong, posted the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I wanted.

I was trying to plot those coordinates in a polar graph. I was going about it all wrong.

I eventually realized that in order for me to convert the x,y coordinates, I needed my own definition for what a radius and an angle should represents in my x,y chart. In my case, I wanted the radius to be the largest absolute value of x and y

The only problem was trying to figure out how to calculate an angle using  x and y values.

This is how I wanted my circle to work,

1. when **x = y**, the angle is *0*.
2. when **x = 1 & y = 0**, then angle is *45*.
3. when **x = 1 & y = -1**, then angle is *90*.
4. when **x = 0 & y = 1**, then angle is *-45*.
5. when **x = -1 & y = 1**, then angle is *-90*.

given this information, you can figure out the rest of the coordinates for the circle up to *180* & *- 180* degree angle.

I had to use conditions (if else statements) to properly figure out the correct angle given x and y.

And then to graph the polar coordinate, you just convert using the cos and sin conversion to x, y coordinates.

I like to program, I'm just not good with calculus.